# Iteration inside an object in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, iteration

i'm new to react and javascript and i have some difficulties coping with a task. Let's get started. I have and array like this:
clients = ["Alex", "Jimmy"] and then i create another array with the following way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
  var portf = Object.keys(obj.portfolios);
}
```

As a result for every i a portf array is created with the following values:
For i = 0 portf = 1,2,3 and for i = 1 portf = 4,5,6
I want to create and array of objects with the following format using iteration:

```
var ops = [{

    label: "Alex",
    options: [
       {value: 1}, 
       {value: 2}, 
       {value: 3}
    ],
    label: 'Jimmy',
    options: [
       {value: 4}, 
       {value: 5}, 
       {value: 6}
    ]
```

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj.portfolios)` is going to be the same for every `i`. How do you get `1,2,3` and `4,5,6`?

Comment: i have a deeply nested map structure. The clients array contains the keys of the map. The portf is created with this procedure: for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
  var obj = clients.getIn([clients[i]]);
  var portf = Object.keys(obj.portfolios); and as a result for i=0 the porf has values of 1,2,3  and for i=1 values of 4,5,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const opts = clients.map(client => {
  const obj = clients.getIn([client]);
  const portf = Object.keys(obj.portfolios);

  return {
    label: client,
    options: portf.map(value => ({ value }))
  }
})
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. It was easier than i thought :P